# Different values when converting Bitmap -> ByteArray()

Tags: java, android, image, stream, arrays

So, to test my code I just ran this:

```
Log.i("imageToSaveBEFORESAVE", String.valueOf(Utilities.getBytes(newEvent.backGround)));
newEvent.saveImage();
Log.i("imageToSaveAFTERSAVE", String.valueOf(newEvent.imageToSave));
```

Now, newEvent.saveImage(); runs this :

```
public void saveImage(){
    imageToSave = Utilities.getBytes(backGround);
}
```

Which runs this:

```
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

So basically, the two Logs in the first code snippet should be the same string, right? But mine isnt.

```
In my test case the BeforeSave one returned this: [B@e33068c
While the afterSave one returned this: [B@3400a1d5
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this happens?

The rest of the code is available here if it helps: https://github.com/smholsen/BigDayCountdown/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/simonm/bigdaycountdown

Comment: yes, they are different instances of byte arrays ... but still they can have **equal** values ... obvious way to **compare** arrays is to compare their elements

Comment: String valueOf returns a new String object everytime is called.